# Having trouble storing navigator.geolocation in a variable in react.js

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to use the Better Doctor API for a school project.

This is the url for the API call:

var resource_url = 'https://api.betterdoctor.com/2016-03-01/doctors?location=' + **coordinates** + ',' + distance + '&skip=0&limit=10&user_key=' + api_key;

The coordinates need to be in the format 'xx.xxx,-xx.xxx' (no space) as lat,-lon values. I want to use the navigator.geolocation function to automatically get a user's location and store it in the variable coordinates instead of hardcoding specific coordinates.

The way I'm doing it is returning undefined for coordinates. I have it commented out in the example below. I'm fairly new to both javascript and react, so excuse me if the question is vague or poorly worded. Thanks.
Here's what I have:

---

```js
var api_key = 'CODE_SAMPLES_KEY_9d3608187'; 

var coordinates = "40.7128,-74.006"; //NY City coordinates

var distance = 30; //Want to toggle this

//var coordinates = getLocation(); Doesn't work
//getLocation() is defined below


function showPosition(position) {

console.log("Position: " + String(position.coords.latitude).slice(0, 6) + "," + String(position.coords.longitude).slice(0, 7));

  return String(position.coords.latitude).slice(0, 6) + "," + String(position.coords.longitude).slice(0, 7);

}

function getLocation() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);

  } else {
    alert("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");
  }
}

var resource_url = 'https://api.betterdoctor.com/2016-03-01/doctors?location=' + coordinates + ',' + distance + '&skip=0&limit=10&user_key=' + api_key;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

##

Comment: I know all the above stuff is javascript but I'm trying to write an app in react. That may be besides the point, thought I'd throw that in there.

Comment: react.js is a library and will not disable native DOM API.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 possible reasons that you didn't get geolocation information.

1. `getCurrentPosition()` no longer work on insecure origins (HTTP site) any more. If your JavaScript code is running on HTTP site, not HTTPS, `getCurrentPosition()` will fail silently.
2. `getCurrentPosition()` can only be invoked by user gesture event (click something etc.). If `getLocation()` is called automatically after page is loaded, it won't work.

I think both 2 restrictions are due to security consideration.

For your code snippet, here is a working example in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cshao/hbvq64g2/1/).